# Subtypes for natural language types

Tags: haskell

I'm a linguist working on the formal syntax/semantics of Natural Languages. I've started
using Haskell quite recently and very soon I realized that I needed to add subtyping. For example given the types Human 
and Animal,
 I would like to have Human as a subtype of Animal. I found that this is possible using a coerce function where the instances are declared by the user, but I do not know how to define coerce in the instances I'm interested in. So basically I do not know what to add after 'coerce =' to make it work'. Here is the code up to that point:

```
{-# OPTIONS

 -XMultiParamTypeClasses
 -XFlexibleInstances
-XFunctionalDependencies
-XRankNTypes
-XTypeSynonymInstances 
-XTypeOperators
#-}

module Model where 

import Data.List



data Animal = A|B deriving (Eq,Show,Bounded,Enum)

data Man = C|D|E|K deriving (Eq,Show,Bounded,Enum)

class Subtype a b where
coerce :: a->b

instance Subtype Man Animal where
coerce=




animal:: [Animal]
animal = [minBound..maxBound] 

man:: [Man]
man = [minBound..maxBound]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you really need subtyping, then use a language that supports it. So you're looking for OO-functional hybrid languages. I'd suggest to have a look at Scala, which has most features Haskell has (just a little bit more verbose) and an excellent OO type system. Having subtyping in Haskell is certainly possible, but it's just a crutch.

Answer (score 12):

Just ignore the Subtype class for a second and examine the type of the coerce function you are writing.  If the `a` is a `Man` and the `b` is an `Animal`, then the type of the coerce function you are writing should be:

```
coerce :: Man -> Animal
```

This means that all you have to do is write a sensible function that converts each one of your `Man` constructors (i.e. `C | D | E | K`) to a corresponding `Animal` constructor (i.e. `A | B`).  That's what it means to subtype, where you define some function that maps the "sub" type onto the original type.

Of course, you can imagine that because you have four constructors for your `Man` type and only two constructors for your `Animal` type then you will end up with more than one `Man` constructor mapping to the same `Animal` constructor.  There's nothing wrong with that and it just means that the coerce function is not reversible.  I can't comment more on that without knowing exactly what those constructors were meant to represent.

The more general answer to your question is that there is no way to automatically know which constructors in `Man` should map to which constructors in `Animal`.  That's why you have to write the coerce function to tell it what the relationship between men and animals is.

Note also that there is nothing special about the 'Subtype' class and 'coerce' function.  You can just skip them and write an 'manToAnimal' function.  After all there is no built-in language or compiler support for sub-typing and Subtype is just another class that some random guy came up with (and frankly, subtyping is not really idiomatic Haskell, but you didn't really ask about that).  All that defining the class instance does is allow you to overload the function `coerce` to work on the `Man` type.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, very good sire.  I was focusing on the design problems he was likely to face soon, but you saw that his problem might have been at the surface -- which, now that I see it, I think more likely.  Good eye.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need a general function of the tyoe a->b since I'm going to use other coercions as well (e.g. Man->Human, Animal->Entity and so on). So I will basically start by declaring the instances in each case. Again thanks a lot, really appreciate it

Answer (score 8):

What level of abstraction are you working where you "need to add subtyping"?

1. Are you trying to create world model for your program encoded by Haskell types?  (I can see this if your types are *actually* `Animal`, `Dog`, etc.)
2. Are you trying to create more general software, and you think subtypes would be a good design?
3. Or are you just learning haskell and playing around with things.

If (1), I think that will not work out for you so well.  Haskell does not have very good reflective abilities -- i.e. ability to weave type logic into runtime logic.  Your model would end up pretty deeply entangled with the implementation.  I would suggest creaing a "world model" (set of) types, as opposed to a  set of types corresponding to a specific world model.  I.e., answer this question for Haskell: what is a world model?

If (2), think again :-).  Subtyping is part of a design tradition in which Haskell does not participate.  There are other ways to design your program, and they will end up playing nicer with the functional mindset then subtyping would have.  It takes times to develop your functional design sense, so be patient with it.  Just remember: keep it simple, stupid.  Use data types and functions over them (but remember to use higher-order functions to generalize and share code).  If you are reaching for advanced features (even typeclasses are fairly advanced in the sense I mean), you are probably doing it wrong.

If (3), see Doug's answer, and play with stuff.  There are lots of ways to fake it, and they all kind of suck eventually.

Comment: Basically I'm starting with (3). It is not over a week since I started working on Haskell (did some Prolog/Python in the Uni but that was not very relevant and also many years ago). Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about Natural Languages so my suggestion may be missing the point, but this may be what you are looking for.

```
{-# OPTIONS
  -XMultiParamTypeClasses
  -XFlexibleContexts
#-}
module Main where

data Animal = Mammal | Reptile deriving (Eq, Show)
data Dog = Terrier | Hound deriving (Eq, Show)
data Snake = Cobra | Rattle deriving (Eq, Show)

class Subtype a b where
  coerce :: a -> b

instance Subtype Animal Animal where
  coerce = id

instance Subtype Dog Animal where
  coerce _ = Mammal

instance Subtype Snake Animal where
  coerce _ = Reptile

isWarmBlooded :: (Subtype a Animal) => a -> Bool
isWarmBlooded = (Mammal == ) . coerce

main = do
  print $ isWarmBlooded Hound
  print $ isWarmBlooded Cobra
  print $ isWarmBlooded Mammal
```

Gives you:

```
True
False
True
```

Is that kind of what you are shooting for? Haskell doesn't have subtyping built-in, but this might do as a work-around. Admittedly, there are probably better ways to do this.

**Note:** This answer is not intended to point out the best, correct or idomatic way to solve the problem at hand. It is intended to answer the question which was "what to add after 'coerce=' to make it work."

Comment: Thanks very much, I was shooting for something similar yes. I basically used a similar approach to yours class Subtype a b where
  coerce :: a -> b

instance Subtype Human Animal where
  coerce DD = AA

Answer (score 4):

You can't write the `coerce` function you're looking for — at least, not sensibly. There aren't any values in `Animal` that correspond with the values in `Man`, so you can't write a definition for `coerce`.

Haskell doesn't have subtyping as an explicit design decision, for various reasons (it allows type inference to work better, and allowing subtyping vastly complicates the language's type system). Instead, you should express relationships like this using *aggregation:*

```
data Animal = A | B | AnimalMan Man deriving (Eq, Show, Bounded, Enum)
data Man = C | D | E | K deriving (Eq, Show, Bounded, Enum)
```

`AnimalMan` now has the type `Man -> Animal`, exactly as you wanted `coerce` to have.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, it is quite possible. We will use type classes and generalized algebraic data types to implement this functionality.

If you want to be able to do something like this (where animals and humans can be fed but only humans can think):

```
animals :: [AnyAnimal]
animals = (replicate 5 . AnyAnimal $ SomeAnimal 10) ++ (replicate 5 . AnyAnimal $ SomeHuman 10 10)

humans :: [AnyHuman]
humans = replicate 5 . AnyHuman $ SomeHuman 10 10

animals' :: [AnyAnimal]
animals' = map coerce humans

animals'' :: [AnyAnimal]
animals'' = (map (\(AnyAnimal x) -> AnyAnimal $ feed 50 x) animals) ++
            (map (\(AnyAnimal x) -> AnyAnimal $ feed 50 x) animals') ++
            (map (\(AnyHuman x) -> AnyAnimal $ feed 50 x) humans)

humans' :: [AnyHuman]
humans' = (map (\(AnyHuman x) -> AnyHuman . think 100 $ feed 50 x) humans)
```

Then it's possible, for example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}

-- | The show is there only to make things easier
class (Show a) => IsAnimal a where
    feed :: Int -> a -> a
    -- other interface defining functions

class (IsAnimal a) => IsHuman a where
    think :: Int -> a -> a
    -- other interface defining functions

class Subtype a b where
    coerce :: a -> b

data AnyAnimal where
    AnyAnimal :: (IsAnimal a) => a -> AnyAnimal
instance Show AnyAnimal where
    show (AnyAnimal x) = "AnyAnimal " ++ show x

data AnyHuman where
    AnyHuman :: (IsHuman a) => a -> AnyHuman
instance Show AnyHuman where
    show (AnyHuman x) = "AnyHuman " ++ show x

data SomeAnimal = SomeAnimal Int deriving Show
instance IsAnimal SomeAnimal where
    feed = flip const

data SomeHuman = SomeHuman Int Int deriving Show
instance IsAnimal SomeHuman where
    feed = flip const
instance IsHuman SomeHuman where
    think = flip const

instance Subtype AnyHuman AnyAnimal where
    coerce (AnyHuman x) = AnyAnimal x

animals :: [AnyAnimal]
animals = (replicate 5 . AnyAnimal $ SomeAnimal 10) ++ (replicate 5 . AnyAnimal $ SomeHuman 10 10)

humans :: [AnyHuman]
humans = replicate 5 . AnyHuman $ SomeHuman 10 10

animals' :: [AnyAnimal]
animals' = map coerce humans
```

Few comments:

- You can make AnyAnimal and AnyHuman instances of their respective classes for convenience (atm. you have to unpack them first and pack them afterwards).
- We could have single GADT AnyAnimal like this (both approaches have their use I would guess):

  ```
  data AnyAnimal where
      AnyAnimal :: (IsAnimal a) => a -> AnyAnimal
      AnyHuman :: (IsHuman a) => a -> AnyAnimal
  instance Show AnyHuman where
      show (AnyHuman x) = "AnyHuman " ++ show x
      show (AnyAnimal x) = "AnyAnimal " ++ show x

  instance Subtype AnyAnimal AnyAnimal where
      coerce (AnyHuman x) = AnyAnimal x
      coerce (AnyAnimal x) = AnyAnimal x
  ```

Comment: I can't see why `TypeFamilies` is required?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather advanced, but have a look at Edward Kmett's [work](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/what-constraints-entail-part-1/) on using the new Constraint kinds for this kind of functionality.